# Azure Media Video Thumbnail Creation Error

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am getting an error when my thumbnails get created after I encode a video. I do not get any error in my script but when I try to load the url in an asp:image I get the error below

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
ResourceNotFound
<Message>
The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:2224a828-0001-0011-4b57-900926000000 Time:2014-12-28T21:38:07.2803364Z
</Message>
</Error>

//Thumbnail Creation
IJob job1 = context.Jobs.Create("Thumbnail job");
IMediaProcessor processor1 = (from p in context.MediaProcessors where p.Name == "Windows Azure Media Encoder" select p).ToList().OrderBy(wame => new Version(wame.Version)).LastOrDefault();
ITask thumbnailTask = job1.Tasks.AddNew("Thumbnail Task", processor, "Thumbnails", TaskOptions.ProtectedConfiguration);
thumbnailTask.InputAssets.Add(inputAsset);
thumbnailTask.OutputAssets.AddNew(string.Format("{0} Thumbnails", CreateAsset), AssetCreationOptions.None);
job1.Submit();
job1.GetExecutionProgressTask(CancellationToken.None).Wait();
IAsset thumbnailAsset = job1.OutputMediaAssets[0];
var jpgAssetFile = thumbnailAsset.AssetFiles.ToList().Where(f => f.Name.EndsWith(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).First();
IAccessPolicy thumbpolicy = context.AccessPolicies.Create("Streaming policy", TimeSpan.FromDays(365), AccessPermissions.Read);
ILocator thumboriginLocator = context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin, thumbnailAsset, thumbpolicy, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5));
```

EDIT

            `IJob thumbjob = context.Jobs.Create("My Thumbnail job");
            IMediaProcessor processor = (from p in context.MediaProcessors where p.Name == "Windows Azure Media Encoder" select p).ToList().OrderBy(wame => new Version(wame.Version)).LastOrDefault();
            ITask task = thumbjob.Tasks.AddNew("My thumbnail task", processor, "Thumbnails", TaskOptions.ProtectedConfiguration);
            task.InputAssets.Add(inputAsset);
            task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Output asset", AssetCreationOptions.None);
            thumbjob.Submit();`

```
        IAsset thumbnailAsset = context.Assets.Create(trainingfolder + "_" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + "_thumb", AssetCreationOptions.None);
        IAccessPolicy accessPolicy = context.AccessPolicies.Create("Thumb Policy", TimeSpan.FromDays(30), AccessPermissions.Read | AccessPermissions.Write);
        ILocator locator = context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, thumbnailAsset, accessPolicy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974308.aspx):

> There may be a 30-40 second delay after a Locator is created to when
>   it is available for use. This issue applies to both SAS URL and
>   OnDemandOrigin locators.

When you work with Azure Media Services the things are not instant. No wonder you can't see the thumbnail with the code you provide. I have never seen a locator being available immediately. I really encourage you to take a look at the code in [this sample MVC web application](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb) that is designed to show basic concepts with Media Services. There [is a part in the code that also checks for existing locators / Access policies before creating new ones](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb/blob/master/WaMedia.Common/Implementations/LocatorService.cs). You really need to better manage your assets. And to take into account [these delays between creation and availability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974308.aspx).

Comment: I can see the thumbnails and the links to the thumbnails, they are in a separate asset folder. I can download them and they open fine. The issue is I can not view them in a web page.

Comment: Yes, you will NOT be able to view them, until you generate SAS locator for them! OnDemandOrigin locator is only for Streaming media, not for thumbnails. And note the delay between locator creation and locator availability!

Comment: I edited the code and ran it and the same thing happens. I add the edit code above. I generated a SAS Locator. Am I doing something wrong with the code?